# Listener when Java application stops or crashes

Tags: java, jar, listener

I have searched the web, and have not been able to find a result. I am looking for a Listener, that when a jar crashes/stops, it's called. I know their is something like this for JFrame, but I am not using a Frame.
Thanks, Avery.

Comment: Edited the title: "jar" isn't the best word to describe it, hope that's OK with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into java.lang.Runtime, method

```
void addShutdownHook(Thread hook)
```

Only one sentence from its javadoc (**but make sure to read all the small print there**): When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start all registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and let them run concurrently.

Here is a "crash" provoked by stack overflow:

```
static void rec(){ rec(); }

public static void main( String[] args ){

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            System.out.println( "SHUTDOWN" );
        }
    };
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( thread );
    rec();
}
```

and it prints SHUTDOWN.

Here is an app uing the same shutdown hook as before that sleeps and can be killed with Ctrl-C or a Linux-style `kill %1` for a BG job:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( thread );
try {
    System.out.println( "Sleeping" );
    Thread.sleep( 5000);
    System.out.println( "Waking" );
} catch( Exception e ){
}
```

and it prints SHUTDOWN.

And, finally, here's provoking `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

```
List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>();
while( true ){
    objs.add( new byte[0x10000000] );
}
```

and it prints SHUTDOWN. (With hefty grabs for heap space the shutdown hook might even be able to create some new objects. But it should be written so that the thread already has all required objects in its belly, with preallocated memory.)

Comment: It won't work if your app crashes or stopped with kill command.

Comment: @Stanislav Added some demos. Don't know what you mean by "crashes" or "stopped". Clearly, if the JVM itself is blown out of memory, the shutdown hook will not exec, but then nothing will.

Comment: I mean, you can run out of memory or process was terminated with SIGKILL signal. In that case, shutdownhook will not be called. Futhermore, the shutdownhooks must be used with care, just take a look into javadoc, to see, that it has some specific behaviour, for example it could not be executed till the end, if it takes a long time, because JVM is not waiting for it to be finished. I just suppose, you have to provide an info about such a specific behaviour if you give this solution.

Comment: I've added a cautionary remark as I don't want to repeat all of javadoc here. I hope this is satisfactory. -- Re SIGKILL: The shutdown hook executes if I start the app using `java X&` and then do `kill %1`. And I think that you even have a chance with running out of heap space if the thread doesn't require heap space of its own.

Comment: @Stanislav As I thought: even running out of heap memory will exec the hook.